# force powerdns to return a specific IP when unable to resolve

Tags: powerdns

I am running the latest version of powerdns authoritative server version 3.3 on a Linux server.
PowerDNS is using a MySQL database for it's list of resolvable sites.
I need powerdns to return a specific response IP for all requests that it cannot resolve.
The end result will be the user will see a specific web page for all locally unresolvable requests.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, about setting prioritary domains, or fallbacks. Have a look : [Add extra zones outside the MySQL database](https://serverfault.com/questions/563836/add-extra-zones-outside-the-mysql-database/564150#564150).

Basically, this is about setting a secondary backend. In your case, set a Bind backend in your launch clause, after your gMySQL value :

```
launch=gmysql,bind
```

If gMySQL fails, the Bind backend will have a chance to try. Create zones and records as you need them ;)

You can also use a custom backend, which always answers the same thing. You can find more about this topic on [the PowerDNS backends details page](http://doc.powerdns.com/html/backends-detail.html).